# Free space Maxwell equation in frequency domain?

Tags: electromagnetism, fourier-transform, maxwell-equations

While reading the textbook "Classical Theory of Gauge Fields" by Valery Rubakov but I couldn't follow some of the steps in the 1.3 chapter. Firstly Fourier transform of 4-vector-potential is given as

$$ A_\mu = \int_{k_0\geq0}d^4k\left[e^{ikx}a_\mu\left(k\right) + c.c.\right] $$

Why is there a complex conjugate? Is it because of $ k_0\geq0 $ ? I don't quite understand.

Then we obviously substitute this Fourier integral into

$$ \partial_\mu\partial^{\mu}A^\nu-\partial_\mu\partial^{\nu}A^\mu=0 $$

What I got so far is (flipping the sign)

$$ \int_{k_0\geq0}d^4k\left[\left(k_{\mu}k^{\mu}a^\nu\right(k\left)-k_{\mu}k^{\nu}a^\mu\right(k\left)\right)e^{ikx}+c.c.\right] = 0 $$

But I should isolate

$$ k_{\mu}k^{\mu}a^\nu-k_{\mu}k^{\nu}a^\mu = 0 $$

Again, what happens to complex conjugate? And integral of something being equal to zero doesn't mean that thing being equal to zero so what's the reasoning here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, remember that we want the electromagnetic field to be *real*. Adding the complex conjugate within the Fourier transform ensures this. Without it, we would generally have a complex vector potential, which is unphysical.

As for your second question: you are certainly right that if the integral is zero this does not necessarily mean that the integrand is zero. However, if the *Fourier transform* of something is zero, then that thing necessarily vanishes (since the Fourier transform is its own inverse).

Comment: One last thing to clarify, I now get why $ \left(k_{\mu}k^{\mu}a^{ν}−k_{\mu}k^{\nu}a^{\mu}\right)e^{ikx} + c.c. = 0 $ what happens of c.c. here? $ a_\mu $ is not supposed to be real, is it.

Comment: One way to see this is the following (very useful) trick: define $a(-k)=a(k)^*$ and extend the bounds of integration to all $k_0$. Then the full expression for $A$ is just the Fourier transform of $a$ (our above definition forces $A$ to be real), and then you don’t have to worry about the complex conjugation.